# Image to Icon conversion

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2010, icons, windows-xp

I am using following code to convert an image to Icon.
Here is my code.

```
Bitmap Cbitmap=null;
  try
  {
  Cbitmap = new Bitmap("path of local image"); 
  }
  catch(Exception)
  {
  return;
  }
  Cbitmap.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
  System.IntPtr icH = Cbitmap.GetHicon();
  Icon ico = Icon.FromHandle(icH);
  Cbitmap.Dispose();
  System.IO.FileStream f = new System.IO.FileStream(Path where to save icon"" + "\\image.ico", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
  ico.Save(f);
   f.close();
  ico.dispose();
```

Now this is converted to Icon successfully but when I try to open it in image viewer it shows **preview not available.**

Also when to try to open it in project it says

**(image.ico is not an icon file)**

Comment: An ico file is just a renamed bmp, have you checked to see if it's saved as a bmp?

Comment: Sorry it is saved as JPEG.Does it matter?

Comment: So can JPEG can not be converted to Icon using above method?

Comment: @Russ C, ICO is *NOT* A BMP, even though the binary format of the image(s) stored in the icon are related to BMP.

Comment: I'm just basing it on this:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141859

Comment: Lucero is correct.  Icons use the run length encoding for the data, but it's not the same format.  @Russ C - That KB article only applies to Windows 98 & ME.  It's a special rename case where Windows does the conversion for you upon renaming the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is fine.  It converts a JPG to an Icon.  What's the dimensions of your original JPG?  If they aren't one of the standard icon sizes, you'll get a strange behavior.  If the original JPG is too large, you'll get the error you are seeing.

Some of the more common sizes are 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48.